# Track Unexpected session timeout programmatically

Tags: session, web, tracking

Currently I have implemented the HttpSessionListener interface in the SessionListener.java class where in the sessionDestroyed method gets called every time the user session is ended.I have put the log statements in the sessionDestroyed method.But it does not really differentiate between the user logout action and the server session timeout.

I have another logout action(spring mvc controller) which is called whenever the user clicks the logout button and clears the session.

Now I want to differentiate between the user logout and server session timeout and log it accordingly in the sessionDestroyed method of the SessionListener.java class.

With this I want to actually track if there are any server session timeouts even before the actual timeout period is reached.